# Sockets in android and listview

Tags: android, sockets, listview

I have an Android application that includes a Socket in an Asynctask and it works, but I do not know if this is the right way to implement it.

Another thing, my onProgressUpdate updates my list adapter and causes lag when I play animation with it.

Someone have a good solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are not during any computation on the UI thread?

Check out this [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html), there are some guidelines on how to use the various thread mechanisms in Android.

If this does not solve your problem, try posting the part of your code that handles the population of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this ... (just for the Socket connection)

```
    private class EstablishConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        boolean ok = false;
        dataSend = false;

        //establish the Connection to the server and returns if it succeed or not
        ok = client.createClient(server, port);
        //try to send the data and return if it succeed or not
        if(ok) dataSend = client.sendData(profilename);
        if(dataSend) {
            //close the connection
            client.closeConnection();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //bring a process Dialog to the front
        showDialog(DIALOG_CONNECTING);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        removeDialog(DIALOG_CONNECTING);
        if(dataSend) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity_sendXML.this, "xml versendet", 2000).show();
        }
        else{
            showDialog(DIALOG_CONNECTION_REFUSED);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer actually this is my solution too, but I wonder if I suppose to put it under Service or to my activity. I experience lags when I'm playing animation while I'm updating the listview adapter from the asynctask.